# Arrays and strings in javascripts

Tags: javascript

```
Array1 = ['1,2,3']
```

How can I retrieve the numerical values by transforming it into non-string? 
I've been trying parseInt, but I can only manage to get 1 as end-result.

Thanks.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol on the other hand, maybe he wants an array with one string element `'1,2,3'` in it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start with an array containing a string, like in your example, you need to use `split()`.

Example:

```
Array1 = ['1,2,3'];
var new_array = Array1[0].split(',');  // new_array is ["1", "2", "3"]
for (var i = 0; i < new_array.length; i++) {
    new_array[i] = parseInt(new_array[i]);
}
// new_array is now [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: You should never use `for (var i in new_array)` to iterate an array.  That iterates properties of the object, not only elements of the array which is sometimes the same thing, but not always.  Use `for (var i = 0; i < new_array.length; i++)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Generally [**parseInt()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) takes anything(most of the time string) as input and returns integer out of that input. If it doesn't get any integer then it returns NaN.

Why you are getting 1 !!!

Whenever you are using parseInt() it tries to read your input character by character. So according to your input

```
var Array1 = ['1,2,3'];
```

first it get's '1' and after that '**,**' (*a comma*, which is not a number) so it converts '1' into Integer and returns it as your result.

Solution of your problem :

```
var Array1 = ['1,2,3'];
//just displayed the first element of the array, use for or foreach to loop through all the elements of the array
alert(Array1[0].split(',')[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would re-look why you're storing a comma separated string as an array element; but, if the reasoning is valid for your particular design, the question is do you have an array with more than one comma-separated string like this?

If you can, re-work your design to  actually use an array of integers, so use:

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
```

instead of `['1,2,3']`.

If you are storing comma separated strings as array elements, you can get each index as an array of integers using something like the following:

```
var array1 = ['1,2,3', '4,5,6,7'];

function as_int_array(list, index) {
    return list[index].split(',').map(function(o) { return parseInt(o,10); });
}
console.log("2nd element: %o", as_int_array(array1, 1));
// => 2nd element: [4,5,6,7]
```

Hope that helps.